# Size of output of encryption with AES-128 CBC Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption

I am currently implementing AES 128 CBC encryption/decryption functions in Kotlin under Android.

I am using the "AES/CBC/NoPadding" instance and I have a function that handles padding.

I can encrypt and decrypt frames well. However, the size of the encrypted data is never a multiple of 16.

How is this possible?

My code :

```
private object AES128{
    private fun cipher(opmode: Int, secretKey: ByteArray, iv: IvParameterSpec):Cipher{
        val c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding")
        val sk = SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES")
        c.init(opmode, sk, iv)
        return c
    }
    fun encrypt(str: String, secretKey: ByteArray, iv: IvParameterSpec):String{
        val encrypted = cipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv).doFinal(padFrame(str.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)))
        return String(android.util.Base64.encode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT))
    }
    fun decrypt(str: String, secretKey: ByteArray, iv: IvParameterSpec):String{
        val byteStr = android.util.Base64.decode(
            str.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8),
            android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)
        return String(cipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv).doFinal(byteStr))
    }

    private fun padFrame(value: ByteArray): ByteArray? {
        // MANUAL PADDING
        val remain = value.size % 16
        if (remain != 0) {
            val paddedValue = ByteArray(value.size + 16 - remain)
            System.arraycopy(value, 0, paddedValue, 0, value.size)
            for (i in 0 until 16 - remain) {
                paddedValue[value.size + i] = 0x0F
            }
            return paddedValue
        }
        return value
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly share a sample dataset (plaintext, key, iv and ciphertext), thanks. "the size of the encrypted data is never a multiple of 16" - do you mean the Base64-encoded string or the length of the Base64-**decoded** ciphertext (as byte array) ?

Comment: Keep in mind that you would have to implement your manual unpad function too. I'd suggest to use PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding (those mean the same thing on the JVM).

Comment: I wanted to say what the "cipher" function returns to me, which is my ciphertext in string format.